# POST http://192.168.0.114/api/broadcasting/auth 419 (unknown status) laravel

Tags: laravel, websocket, eloquent, broadcast, laravel-websockets

I have some issues about to connect to broadcasting from React

I sure don't have any error on my code, this is my code

on my `broadcast.php` on config folder

```
     'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'encrypted' => true,
                'host' => '192.168.0.114',
                'port' => 6001,
                'scheme' => 'http'
            ],
        ],
```

and on my `api.php` on route folder i am adding

```
Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['api', 'auth:sanctum']]);
```

on `.env` file

```
PUSHER_APP_ID=osamah
PUSHER_APP_KEY=osamah
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=osamah
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1
```

on `channel.php`

```
Broadcast::channel('App.Models.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});
```

on my react listen

```
 const echo = new Echo({
        broadcaster: 'pusher',
        key: 'osamah',
        cluster: 'mt1',
        wsHost: '192.168.0.114',
        wsPort: 6001,
        forceTLS: false,
        disableStats: true,
        authEndpoint: "http://192.168.0.114/api/broadcasting/auth",
        auth: {
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer 1542|3hVrlJ3A968IeZ23kejqTp8CJ9p4RCkcj66gRK4z'
            },
        }

    });

    echo.connector.pusher.connection.bind('connected', () => {
        console.log('connected');
        axios.get(`http://192.168.0.114/api/count`, {
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer 1542|3hVrlJ3A968IeZ23kejqTp8CJ9p4RCkcj66gRK4z'
            },
        })
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res);
            })
    });

    echo.private('App.Models.User.393').notification((e)=>console.log(e.user));
```

Comment: As I remember, **419 is not a standard HTTP status code**; check your error logs and check `Authorization` is correct

Comment: its working on anther project i created but when copy it to my main project show this status <<< how i can check error log ?

Comment: `419` often means a missing CSRF token. Make sure your API routes are in `api.php`, and that `VerifyCsrfToken` is not in your api middleware group in Kernel.php